# Entity Framework and global data save/update handler through Provider Pattern

Tags: entity-framework, provider

I'm new to entity framework. I used other data persistence layers before, and would like to accomplish the following things I'm used to, in the other applications I developed.
And I'd like to ask if it's possible with EF and get few guidelines on how to do

I would like that every time I save an entity to database (Add / Update), to have a hook where I can "attach", through Provider pattern, various functionalities which have to be invoked before / after save, in a transactional way. For example, I might want to implement a AuditProvider. This will be called if the entity being saved implements an Interface, IAuditEnabled, which adds properties SysAddUser, SysAddDate, SysUpdateUser, SysUpdateDate (which allow to set which user added / updated record, and at what moment). Another functionality would be to call a BusinessEntityEnforcerProvider, which check if business objects implements IBusinessEntityEnforcer interface and calls method EnforceBusinessRules. Just few thoughts.

Just to clarify, I want to have the possibility to hook various functionality to business object before / after save, which I don't want to call specificaly, but to make sure they are always called before  or after BO is to be saved.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: After some research, I found that in EF4 (which I'm gonna use), it is possible to overwrite SaveChanges. I found this here, and it seems it might allow me to do what I need (just call my Providers before calling base.SaveChanges).If anyone have any more suggestions or advices, I'll be grateful to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework [Object Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) is generated as a partial class.  You can extend the implementation and override the [SaveChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500.aspx) method in order to execute code before and after each save.